# Issue with FreeIPA and Active Directory synchronisation

Tags: active-directory, freeipa

I'm trying to setup a FreeIPA and Active Directory synchronisation following Red Hat [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/Setting_up_Active_Directory.html#ad-user-acct).

The ipa-replica-manage command returns a success but no user are imported in FreeIPA:

```
[root@ipa ~]# ipa-replica-manage connect --winsync --binddn='cn=ipasync,cn=Users,dc=ipa,dc=local'  --bindpw='####' --passsync #### --cacert ipa-a-v
Directory Manager password:

Added CA certificate ipa-ad.cloud.620nm.net.cer to certificate database for ipa.cloud.620nm.net
ipa: INFO: AD Suffix is: DC=ipa,DC=local
The user for the Windows PassSync service is uid=passsync,cn=sysaccounts,cn=etc,dc=ipa,dc=cloud,dc=620nm,dc=net
Windows PassSync system account exists, not resetting password
ipa: INFO: Added new sync agreement, waiting for it to become ready . . .
ipa: INFO: Replication Update in progress: FALSE: status: Error (0) Replica acquired successfully: Incremental update started: start: 0: end: 0
ipa: INFO: Agreement is ready, starting replication . . .
Starting replication, please wait until this has completed.
Update in progress, 2 seconds elapsed
Update succeeded
```

The ipasync user has been created with the rights as described in the documentation.

Is someone has already managed to establish an AD synchronization with FreeIPA ?

Comment: are you able to setup this sync?